# How do I import my RAW files from Google Drive to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app, google-apps

I wanted to try out Darkroom+ on my iPhone to edit the RAW photos I took with my Sony a7iii but it seems like iOS does weird things with RAWs. I've tried exporting from Google Drive app, downloading from Google Drive website, and saving to Files from Google Drive app.

1. Adds TIFF extension to ARW extension - if I save the photo from the Google Drive website on my iPhone in Safari it asks `Do you want to save DSC####.ARW.tiff?`
2. Changes ARW extension to TIFF extension - if I use the GDrive app and save to Files then the photo saves as `DSC####.tiff`

The only thing that has successfully gotten the file into my phone as an ARW is by downloading from Google Drive site on my Macbook and then AirDropping the file to my iPhone. It goes to my photos app instantly and is an ARW extension raw photo.

I don't want to airdrop my photos every time. My workflow involves me uploading to Google Drive from a Windows PC. I want to later on edit from my phone. I don't want to use Macbook as an intermediary step. I want to download from Google drive as an ARW straight to my iPhone.

Comment: Are you using Sony's default compressed RAW or have you switched it off. Apple [& consequently Darkroom+ as it uses Apple's RAW support] cannot process compressed RAW files. Maybe something is trying to uncompress them & present as tiff?

Comment: Using uncompressed RAW. It's so bizarre is that even saving straight to iCloud files from Google Drive changes it to tiff.

Comment: Just tried from Brave browser instead of Safari and it downloaded properly. Too bad I can't download via GDrive app or Safari. If anyone comes across other alternatives or updates that don't involve a second device let me know!